# Graphql not returning associated objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I'm trying to return a GraphQL query that links to an association, but I'm getting the following:
[image]

In the query, I would like the actors to return all of the actors  (there are 3), instead I'm just getting name: "Actor"?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Rails server log:
[image]

My code are as follows:

app/graphql/types/movie_type.rb

```
Types::MovieType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name "Movie"

  field :id, !types.ID
  field :title, !types.String
  field :description, !types.String
  field :release_year, !types.Int
  field :actors do
    type Types::ActorType 
    argument :size, types.Int, default_value: 10
    resolve -> (movie, args, ctx) {
      movie.actors.limit(args[:size])
    }
  end
end
```

app/graphql/types/query_type.rb

```
field :movie, Types::MovieType do
    argument :id, !types.ID
    resolve -> (obj, args, ctx) {
      Movie.find(args[:id])
    }
end
```

app/models/movie.rb

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :actors
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180424112411) do

  create_table "actors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "image"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "actors_movies", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "actor_id", null: false
    t.integer "movie_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "movies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "release_year"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, inside movie_type.rb I needed this change:

**type types[Types::ActorType]**

I guess it must be due to setting it to return an array and not getting back a single entity.